# Why can't I see the boolean value of my argparse variables in pdb?

Tags: python, argparse, pdb

I have the following code:

```
def main():
    argParser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description = 'DESCRIPTION',epilog = 'Please see README.MD for guidance on how to use this script')
    argParser.add_argument('-i', '--inFile', action='store',type=str, help = 'Input config file')
    argParser.add_argument('-o', '--outFile', action = 'store', default = sys.stdout, type = argparse.FileType('w'), help = 'Output VCD File')
#   generate_config_group = argParser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
    _ = argParser.add_argument('-g','--generate_config',action='store_true')
    args = argParser.parse_args()

    print(args,"THESE ARE MY ARGS")
    print(args.generate_config,"This is the value of generate_config")
    pdb.set_trace()
```

Now I run it

```
$ python src\dspwave8b10b2vcd.py -g
Namespace(generate_config=True, inFile=None, outFile=<_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stdout>' mode='w' encoding='utf-8'>) THESE ARE MY ARGS
True This is the value of generate_config
> c:\main\femtotest\tools\dspwave8b10b2vcd\src\dspwave8b10b2vcd.py(153)main()
-> if args.generate_config:
(Pdb) args
(Pdb) args.generate_config
(Pdb) args.g
(Pdb) args.g == True
```

Why is it that its prints out my arguments with generate_config being True for instance. Yet when I try and evaluate the value in pdb, it returns nothing.

Comment: Try `p args.generate_config` in the Pdb prompt : https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html#pdbcommand-p

Comment: that works. Why? Something about the current context?

Comment: `Pdb` expects a command to be passed in the prompt: https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html#debugger-commands Just putting the expression is not what Pdb expects.

Comment: @BigBoy1337 It would work with just putting an expression in `pdb`, but in this case, the pdb line started with `args`, so pdb interpreted it as the `args` command (search _"a(rgs)"_ in https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html#debugger-commands). If you named the variable e.g. `shmargs`, that would work.

Comment: I recommend doing `print(args)` when debugging.

Answer (score 4):

As I had to piece the solution together from the comments, I will summarize it here:

`args` is a keyword for pdb. Similar to when you name a variable `c` or `s` or `q` you won't be able to access it as usual by writing its name in the command prompt. you can access a variable named like that by prepending `p`.

So `p args.g` would work to show the value of `args.g`. But typing `args.g` in the pdb console breaks.